# Bixby: unable to select single ticket detail using list-of navigation

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am using the Bixby list-of navigation to show multiple tickets and select tickets to show details of that ticket using ordinal-selection-patterns. But if I have only a single ticket and I want to show the detail page of that ticket directly. But I am unable to show.
So, is it possible to call two different actions in the result view.

Result View

```
result-view {
 match: TicketConfirmation(item) 
 message{
  if(exists(item.errorData)){
   template("#{value(item.errorData)}")
  }
}
render {
if (exists(item.Total) && item.Total >= 1) {
  list-of (item) {
    navigation-mode {
      if ($handsFree) {
        read-many {
          page-size (6)
          page-content (page) {
            page-marker {
              if(exists(item.customMessage)){
                template("") 
              }
            }
            underflow-statement (This is the first item.)
            overflow-statement (Those are all the items.)             
          }
        }
      }
    }
    where-each (item) {
      layout-macro (ticket-summary-card) {
        param (single_item) {
          expression (item)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Layout:

```
layout-macro-def(ticket-summary-card) {
 params {
  param (single_item) {
   type (TicketConfirmation)
   min (Required)
   max (One)
  }
 }
 content {
  compound-card {
    content {
      if (exists(single_item.Name)){
        paragraph{
          value("#{value(single_item.Name)}")
          style(Detail_L)
        }
      }  
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Navigation support:

```
navigation-support {
 match: TicketConfirmation (this) 
  ordinal-selection-patterns {
   pattern ("(first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector]")
   pattern ("(first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector] one")
   pattern ("that (first)[v:viv.core.OrdinalSelector] one")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two questions here.
I will go with the easy question first:

"is it possible to call two different actions in the result view"?
NO, normally there is only one `goal`. It is possible that the `goal` ActionA requires ActionB first and planer handles that with proper training, but developer cannot specify `goalA`, then `goalB` like function calls in `intent`. It is possible to explore the possibility to trigger multiple actions to fulfill a single structure's value by using intent->goal-set. However, a single action to fulfill the value of structure is usually easier and more nature.

Now the more difficult question: "I am using the Bixby list-of navigation to show multiple tickets and select tickets to show details of that ticket using ordinal-selection-patterns. But if I have only a single ticket and I want to show the detail page of that ticket directly. But I am unable to show. "

1. In runtime-version(7), override with both `allow-dialogs-on-detail-pages (true)` and `no-fallback-dialog-in-views (false)`
2. list-of and where-each should automatically handle the situation you described. You may want have separate render content for ==1 condition. In your code `item.Total >= 1`, normal practice is do summary in >1 and detail in ==1 condition.
3. Try to see if there is any difference between HEF and non-HEF, it is unclear from your question whether non-HEF works as desired or not.
4. "I am unable to show", do you mean you see nothing rendered, or if you see a list view with only 1 item, which requires user to do one more selection step. I will update this answer once learned more.

Updated. I would say just call the detail page directly as the following:

```
result-view {
  match: StructPerson(this)
  message: template ("There are #{size(this)} items") 
  render {
    if (size(this)==1) {
      // this is the detail view
      layout-macro (detail-person) {
        param (person) { expression (this) }
      }
    }
    else-if (size(this<1)) {
      // this is 0 result view
    }
    else {
      // this is the list view
      if ($handsFree) {
        // do list navigation here
      }
      else {
        list-of (this) {
          where-each (item) {
            layout-macro (summary-person) {
              param (person)  { expression (item)}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see a list view with only 1 item for which I need to do one more step to see the detail of that item and "select one" (hands-free navigation) doesn't work for that. So, either I want to call the detail page directly or I want (hands-free navigation) to work to select that item.

Comment: The detail page is having different actions and structures. Calling detail page results in multiple ticket pages throwing error as "illegal property in the expression".

Comment: I am not following, normally the macro-summary and macro-detail should be rather similar in terms of params. Maybe you want to post error screenshot here, or submit a ticket using Bixby IDE -> Help -> Contact Support. Regarding the original question, do you think the sample code would be what you want if you are able to call macro-detail when size(this)==1?